# Change the colors in the Graph Editor

Tags: graph-editor

community this is my first question in the forum. Of course, I have been trying to find the answer for quite some time before posting, and nope, the setting I am looking for is not in the THEME tab from the settings menu in Blender.

By the way, I am using Blender 2.82a, and the problem is that I have a light blue color that interferes with the white letters in the graph editor's transform channels and it's hard to read(I have noticed most likely everyone has dark gray background), Please take look to the image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view menu of the graph editor, uncheck "show group colors", and the default color should be back.

This light blue color you see is associated to the bone groups in the armature properties. It is very handy in the viewport, but make things less readable in the graph editor.

Comment: that was it. thank you so much, :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Check *Themes* > *Graph Editor* > *Channels Region.* It controls the color behind the text.

Comment: Thank you. but that isn't the case, the channel region is set to dark gray and still, the graph editor is showing light blue, I already tried all of the colors in theme > graph editor tab "and all over the theme section" and it seems that the answer is not there.

Comment: This is rough, sorry.  I've been looking through this myself.  Is this a Blender preset theme?  Obviously this isn't the default color, so it's definitely something you can edit.  Maybe color pick that blue area, and then simply find that color, wherever it may be in the preferences.

Comment: Thanks @S. Magnusson, I haven't changed any of the color themes i have al default, and yes I did try a color picker and don't find that value anywhere in the theme section... I have noticed that it only happens when the object is a rigify armature or bone, here is an image. Thank you [link](http//imgur.com/a/1E2vxre)... sorry just don't know how to add an image but the link is there, I tried many times  :(